# How can I not display elements that are repeated?

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

How can I not display elements that are repeated? (react-slick slider)

The problem is that the items are duplicate, how do I fix this? Honestly, no thoughts come at all, please tell me

```
const titles = [
  {
    title: "iPhone"
  },
  {
    title: "Samsung"
  },
  {
    title: "Xiaomi"
  },
  {
    title: "Sony"
  },
  {
    title: "Lg"
  }
];   

<Slider variableWidth>
   {titles.map((el) => {
      return (
        <div className="tab__box">
           <div className="tab">{el.title}</div>
        </div>
      );
   })}
 </Slider>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnlHA.png)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-rgb-fwmd0?file=/src/App.js:85-243 - demo

Answer (score 1):

Use infinite property like:

```
 <Slider variableWidth {...{infinite: false}}>
  {titles.map((el) => {
    return (
      <div className="tab__box">
        <div className="tab">{el.title}</div>
      </div>
    );
  })}
</Slider>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Set method which will give you unique array.

```
let uniqueTitles = [...new Set(titles)];
```

Comment: looks like there is some issue/logic in Slider. if you simple write a plain text it will repeat it 3 times. its not about unique array.